# Why does `dir` list some attrs with unicode names in Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto3

I was trying to learn a thing about the low-level s3 api in boto3, so I did

```
from pprint import pprint
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
pprint(dir(client))
```

in a REPL and noticed something surprising (to me, at least). Since there are a lot of attrs there, I'll boil it down for the question:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> groups = groupby(sorted(dir(client), key=type), key=type)
>>> pprint([g[0] for g in groups])
[<type 'str'>, <type 'unicode'>]
```

Some of the attributes have names in `unicode`, and some in `str`.

My guess is that in the boto3 source code, some of the modules have `from __future__ import unicode_literals`. On the other hand, boto3 does more than its fair share of dynamic code generation.

Does anyone know the real reason for some attrs being unicode, and some being str, and what the implications (if any) of this are?

Comment: I'm guessing the object implements `__dir__` and returns unicode objects from it.

Comment: So which attribute(s) are `unicode` objects? Unless there is an actual problem, this isn't really anything other than a quirk of the implementation.

Comment: @chepner I haven't encountered a problem yet, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. Python 2 certainly has a lot of problems converting between str and unicode. Hence my question about the implications.

Comment: So, again, which attributes are they? If they are regular ASCII strings that just happen to be `unicode` objects, there's no problem.

Comment: @chepner all unicode attributes are `instancemethod`s; whereas the `str` types are mix of `dict`, `type`, `instnacemethod`, `method-wrapper`, `builtin`s, `exception` etc. See https://www.hastebin.com/ohazugogec.ipy

Comment: OK, looking at some of the method names, they aren't mentioned anywhere in the actual code base. My guess is whatever is generating the dynamic code does so via a JSON response, which would return all strings as Unicode objects.